# @app.route returns html and @api.route returns string

Tags: python, api, flask

I use Flask for setting up APIs. For some simple tests I return html tags. Using Flask_restplus however returns a string. I would like to know why and how I could change this? Of course I could use Jinja but I'd like to know how to change this in this small example.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api, fields

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# This code returns HTML
@app.route('/test1')
def language():
    language = request.args.get('language')
    message = '<h1>Hello world! I speak {}</h1>'.format(language)
    return message

# This code returns string e.g. '<h1>Hello wolrd! I speak english</h1>
@api.route('/hello')
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        language = request.args.get('language')
        message = '<h1>Hello world! I speak {}</h1>'.format(language)
        return message

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=4996)
```

As commented @app.route returns html and @api.route returns a string

Comment: what value type expect who this return?

Comment: Check the content type headers of the responses. Usually the `@api` call should return one that is more suitable for API while `@app` returns `text/html` per default.

Comment: flask_restplus does things under the hood to properly convert your request. You should check your header in both cases.

Comment: @KlausD. - thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api, fields

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# This code returns HTML
@app.route('/test1')
def language():
    language = request.args.get('language')
    message = '<h1>Hello world! I speak {}</h1>'.format(language)
    return message

def output_html(data, code, headers=None):
    resp = Response(data, mimetype='text/html', headers=headers)
    resp.status_code = code
    return resp

# This code returns string e.g. '<h1>Hello wolrd! I speak english</h1>
@api.route('/hello')
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        language = request.args.get('language')
        message = '<h1>Hello world! I speak {}</h1>'.format(language)
        return output_html(message, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=4996)
```

Comment: While this answer might work, It would have been better to add an explanation as to why or how does it work.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. I found the explanation: Restplus really returns application/json as default header. Right now you can not change it via restplus. But as @giridhar kadam suggested, flask Response can do the job. Alternate solution can be found here [link](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/161)